# How to Learn Canvas / ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript, html, canvas

I want to learn to program the canvas element. Anyone got any recommendations of websites / books?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Flash does not have anything to do with `<canvas>` so you would be using Javascript, not Actionscript.

I used this tutorial when I was learning about `<canvas>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial

It seems to cover the basics pretty well.

Comment: http://creativejs.com/2011/08/31-days-of-canvas-tutorials/  and              http://www.html5canvastutorials.com